# How to load a view from controller in Codeigniter when the controller is called from an AJAX POST request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a **view** which has an AJAX POST to a **controller** `list_products_of_company` :

```
$('select.product_dimension').change(function () {
  var a = "a";
  var b = "b";
  $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/list_products_of_company",
            {
                a : a, b : b
            }       
 )
});
```

**Controller** :

```
function list_products_of_company(){ 
        $a = $this->input->post('a');
        $b = $this->input->post('b');
        $this->data['products_of_company'] = $this->Home_model->get_products_of_company($a,$b);
        $this->load->view('product_list',$this->data);
}
```

How do I load the view with the data that I got from the database?

**Edit:**

I don't want to load the ajax response inside a div. I need the entire view page to be loaded in the window.

Comment: load the view as it is and get data from AJAX. Thats what we call optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the view from your codeigniter controller don't use AJAX here instead I suggest you to modify your HTML like this:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php">
    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" name="sub" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And your jquery code like this so that you can directly submit the form on change of the select box and the action goes to the CI controller:

```
$(function () {
    $('#select').change(function () {
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

And your CI home controller:

```
function list_products_of_company(){ 
        $a = $this->input->post('a');
        $b = $this->input->post('b');
        $this->data['products_of_company'] = $this->Home_model->get_products_of_company($a,$b);
        $this->load->view('product_list',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: @arshad Thank you for accepting my answer i hope your issue have been fixed now,if you have any doubt ping me campaigns my stack overflow chat room.

Comment: Thank you for the help man. You are late but this is a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select.product_dimension').change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/list_products_of_company",
    dataType: 'text',
    success:
      function(data){
        //change the id to your div id. where you want to load the view
        $('#yourdivid').html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

I think this will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your html as per response. say for example you want to response set with in `div` with id `container`. you can do as follows

`<div id="container"></div>`

```
$('select.product_dimension').change(function () {
  var a = "a";
  var b = "b";
  // This will 
  $("#container").load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/list_products_of_company",
            {a : a, b : b});       
});
```

Comment: I want a page redirect like we do in CI. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use `window.location = "http://yoururl.com"` in javascript for page reidrection

Comment: That "url" is the problem...If I load the url with window.location, the datas won't get added to the page...

Comment: i think you have problem is flow of page or the way you loading data. i am not clear about your whole problem.